# How to use multiple cache layers in c++ (RAM, HDD, cold)

Tags: c++, file, pointers, filesystems

I have a simple POD data class like

```
struct hash{
    char buffer[16];
};
```

I need to have a vector of many instances of it it will shorelly not fit into ram (20 PB). It is conceptually grouped into a vector (tree). I want to have a way to have a pointer like thing that would  hide RAM, filesystem, cold storage, and have a simple array\pointer like interface (makeing fs, operations invisible after initialisation yet allowing to give it multiple places to put data in - RAM, Fast SSD, SSD, HDD, Tape, Cloud drive locations)

How to do such thing in C++?

Comment: The answers for C and for C++ are completely different but the general idea is that you have to implement an interface between cache layers and then implement each layer. What does your key look like? Is it also 16 bytes of raw data?

Comment: What you want to do is very broad, and not at all trivial to do, although hopefully this will point you in the right direction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file

Comment: @David: Yes it is

Comment: @J.: my bad - have not made it clear that array is resizable (vector)

Comment: You almost always want to move data into the RAM before processing it. If you have a ton of data, it's best to do it in batches. Move a block of data into RAM (either by reading it from a file or downloading it), and then processing it.

Comment: Then make it clear by editing your question. Or probably better  deleting it, as this is  a very bad question..

Comment: @J.: any cache impl. Can have a prediction algorithm like cpu does so I hoped for a language/boost level solution for such operations...

Comment: There's definitely not a language level solution for this. You'll have to write your own library

Comment: SUGGESTION: You might be interested in [Thrill](https://project-thrill.org/)

Comment: More details on what you are trying to do would help.  If you have a 16-byte object that you are storing in a vector having complex pointers to each 16-byte object will likely not take less space.

Answer (score 1):

There is no support for this at the language level.

One solution would be use a memory mapped file, for example see:

[Creating a File Mapping Using Large Pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/da-dk/windows/desktop/Memory/creating-a-file-mapping-using-large-pages)

If you need a more platform independant solution then it is possible you could use [boost](/questions/tagged/boost) that has some support for memory mapped files as well in the [boost-filesystem](/questions/tagged/boost-filesystem) library.

Besides that you, you can always make a pointer *like* object facade to manage the underlying logics (ala. smart pointers).

```
template<class T>
struct MyMappedPointerType {
  T& operator* MyPointerType();//derefence - may throw..
  //implement rest of semantics
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the usual would be to use some handle. Then when you want to access the object, you would pass the handle to a function which will load the memory and give you the address, and then you would close the handle. In C++ you would use RAII.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdio>

template <class T>
class Access
{
private:
    FILE* f= nullptr;
public:
    Access(const std::string& filename)
    {
        f= fopen(filename.data(), "rw");
    }

    ~Access()
    {
        fclose(f);
    }

    class WriteAccess
    {
        T buffer{};
        bool dirty= false;
        FILE* f;
        int64_t elementNumber;
    public:
        WriteAccess(FILE* f, int64_t elementNumber)
        : f(f)
        , elementNumber(elementNumber)
        {
            if (f) {
                fseek(f, elementNumber*sizeof(buffer), SEEK_SET);
                fread(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, f);
            }
        }

        T& get() { dirty= true; return buffer; }
        const T& get() const { return buffer; }

        ~WriteAccess()
        {
            if (dirty && f) {
                fseek(f, elementNumber*sizeof(buffer), SEEK_SET);
                fwrite(&buffer, sizeof(buffer), 1, f);
            }
        }
    };

    WriteAccess operator[] (int64_t elementNumber)
    {
        return WriteAccess(f, elementNumber);
    }
};

struct SomeData
{
    int a= 0;
    int b= 0;
    int c= 0;
};

int main()
{
    Access<SomeData> myfile("thedata.bin");

    myfile[0].get().a= 1;
    auto pos1= myfile[1];

    pos1.get().a= 10;
    pos1.get().b= 10;
}
```

Of course, you would provide read acccess and write access, probably not using fopen but new c++ files, **you should check for errors**, and maybe you could get rid of `get()` function in form of a conversion operator to `T`.

You should also note that you could use some ref counting, in my simple example `Access` class should outlive `WriteAccess` class.

Also, you should lock if this is going to get used by more than one thread, and I assumed that you would not access the same element twice.

Or you could also use memory mapped file access like they've told you.